# Taking Input from TimePicker - Android

Tags: android, mobile

When a user makes changes to a TimePicker I need to save the hour, minute, and whether it was AM or PM so I can later add 1.5 hours to it and create an alarm in Android's default alarm system.

I can't get anything to save the user input right now...

Does anyone know either how I can do this or where I can look to see some code?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a simple TimePicker, you can listen for each change in with an [OnTimeChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener.html)

If you are using a TimePickerDialog, you can retrieve the time when the user presses the "Set" button with an [OnTimeSetListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html)

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.